# Android & Dalvik - Get the size of an object

Tags: java, android, dalvik

As we all know Java 5 introduced the ability for Instrumentation to get the size of an object with ease. Is there such a method on Android and Dalvik?

The `java.lang.instrument` package is not available on Android.

Comment: [Here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Android/Development/Functionthatgetthesizeofanobject.htm) is a cleaner example I found. Still requires a serialization of sorts.

Comment: There must be... I can't even consider that such a high level programming language isn't able to do this. Serializing it to check its size? I mean come on...

Comment: Check out this: http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=83

Comment: Looks and feels like a crummy hack... I went with Samuel's answer.

Comment: I would expect high level languages to be _less_ good at telling you the size of types.  That's the point, no?

Comment: No. I would expect it to know an objects freaking size. This isn't rocket science, oh wait... it is.

Comment: Just curious... what is your actual use case for needing that?

Comment: There are tons of cases were I'd like to measure the size of an Object. In this case its a bitmap cache. I know I could "calculate" the size of the cache my self, as a bitmap is basically a 2D array of pixel values but I don't want to go down that route.

Comment: This is the size of the object after serialization, which includes headers, metadata, information about types, etc, not the size in memory.

Comment: Take a look at my answer from here, it counts the bytes of the object. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14366410/how-to-get-the-in-memory-size-of-an-object-in-android-or-performance-benchmarks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

For what it's worth, I have looked at the Dalvik VM source code and can not find any stable API to get the size of an Object. If you want to take a look yourself, the size of an object is stored in `ClassObject::objectSize : size_t`, see **dalvik/vm/oo/Object.h**.

There is, however,  *internal* APIs to get the size of an Object. It is used by DDMS to report detailed information about object sizes. But, since the API is internal, it is likely to change between different versions of Android. Plus, the API is sends raw `byte[]` data around, and is client/server based and not a simple library call, so it will be extremely awkward to use. If you want to take a look, start in `dvmAllocObject()` in **dalvik/vm/alloc/Alloc.cpp** and the `dvmTrackAllocation()` call.

To sum it up: there is unfortunately not any readily usable, stable API to get the size of an Object in the Dalvik VM.

Comment: Hit the jackpot , dvmAllocObject is the function called when new operator is used . As for the size , its a true thing , app users can get the size .

Answer (score 0):

My idea to get the size of a `ArrayList<String>` on the heap was to serialize the object into a Byte-Array, where the lengths is the size.

I've used the `SerializationUtils` from Apache [Commons Lang](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/).

To serialize:

```
byte[] data = SerializationUtils.serialize((Serializable) arrayList);
```

> The lenght of the data array should be approximately the size in bytes on the heap.

As mentioned, this requires Commons Lang library. It can be imported using Gradle:

```
api 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.5'
```

more ways mentioned [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3/3.5)

Answer (score -1):

For this problem, it is better not to use a programatic approach but to use the Memory Analyzer Tool (MAT) from www.eclipse.org/mat/ It has both standalone version and plugin for Eclipse. With it you can create a snapshot of Dalvik heap and then you could sort the list of objects by their size or also by the size of their referenced objects (retained size). I used this exactly for troubleshooting a bitmap cache leaks.

Comment: He is looking for a way to calculate the size of an object **at runtime**.