# Android and java bytecode manipulation

Tags: java, android, bytecode, java-bytecode-asm

I am new to java and I need to manipulate java bytecode for some purposes (see [this](https://www.captechconsulting.com/blog/david-tiller/not-so-secret-java-agents-part-1)). Java bytecode manipulation need following imports:

1. org.objectweb.asm
2. java.lang.instrument

I resolved org.objectweb.asm by downloading ASM package from [asm website](http://forge.ow2.org/projects/asm) and related imports have been resolved.

I don't know how to resolve java.lang.instrument, My default ADT bundle hasn't it:

[image]

How do I resolve this import? Should I download any library? from where?
any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `java.lang.instrument` package isn't available for Android. Just like AWT and Swing. Have a look at this question:

[Android & Dalvik - Get the size of an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9009544/android-dalvik-get-the-size-of-an-object)

But it makes sense. Android apps are written at the source level in Java, but they don't run on the JVM -- they run on the dalvik VM. There's no contract there that says they have to support the standard Java library.

Sorry :(

Comment: Thank you for your reply, Thus I can not manipulate bytecode in android at all?

Answer (score 3):

You're out of luck – find a way that does not rely on `java.lang.instrument`. [`java.lang.instrument` is part of Java SE](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/package-summary.html), but is not available on Android because of fundamental limitations of Dalvik.

> The `java.lang.instrument` package was removed from dalvik core library, because this package makes a fundamental assumption that the execution format being used by the VM is a `.class file`. `.class` files do not appear on Android at all.

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/MR4W2roQ3Xw

Comment: Thank you for your reply, Thus I can not manipulate bytecode in android at all?

Comment: so it was available on some old versions of Android?

Answer (score 0):

[Javassist](http://www.csg.ci.i.u-tokyo.ac.jp/~chiba/javassist/) is another tools to manipulate java bytecode. There is already someone who tried to use [javassist in android](https://github.com/crimsonwoods/javassist-android). You might want to try it. As far as I know, bytecode manipulation on android runtime isn't possible, except in instrumentation (usually for testing). Manipulation on compile time is a different story, because java .class file generated first before converted to Dalvik bytecode. So if you modify .class file before being dexed, the dexed classes will be the modified one.

[This article](http://www.bravenewgeek.com/dalvik-bytecode-generation/) also worth reading, because it noted of [ASMDEX](http://asm.ow2.org/doc/tutorial-asmdex.html) which claim can manipulate DEX bytecode.

Answer (score 0):

The `java.lang.instrument` package was removed. So you can't perform bytecode manipulation at runtime. However you can perform bytecode manipulation at build time with javaassist or ASM.

This [sample project](https://github.com/AttwellBrian/SampleByteCodeProcessor/blob/master/README.md) performs bytecode manipulation. It's usage is discussed [here](http://brianattwell.com/using-bytecode-manipulation-to-further-kill-android-boilerplate/).